# How to fix error in web api testing using xUnit

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, moq, xunit, autofixture

```
public class ControllerTest
{
    private readonly IFixture fixure;
    private readonly Mock<ICustomerService> service;;
    private readonly CustController  controller;

    public ControllerTest()
    {
        service = new Mock<ICustomerService>();
        controller = new CustController(service.Object);
        fixure = new Fixture();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Controller _GetCustByIdName_ReturnOk()

    {

        //arrange
        var customers = fixure.Create<IEnumerable<EmployeeDto>>();
        var id = fixure.Create<string>();
        var name = fixure.Create<string>();

        service.Setup(x => x.GetCustomers(id,name)).ReturnsAsync(customers);
        
    }
}
```

I have above code to unit test my method which accepts id and name and return list of employees. I am getting the error on last line of `service.SetuUp` as

> isetup does not contain definition for returnsasync

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you please share with us the definition of `ICustomerService` interface?

Comment: Did you know you can do `var customers = fixture.CreateMany<EmployeeDto>();`?